# How do you retrieve the call list and voicemail messages on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an iPhone application that replicates the functionality of the built-in phone 
application, but adds a few features on top.  This is for ad hoc distribution only.

In particular, is there a way to programmatically retrieve the last calls received by the phone?  Also, how can an application access the list of voicemail messages?

Comment: A class-dump may help if you have the binary.

Comment: Far too broad. Break your project down into manageable steps and attempt to solve each problem. If you have any specific questions about some problem, by all means ask here. But as it stands, "how do I write an iPhone app" isn't an answerable question.

Comment: no my question is not about "how do you write an iphone app", i'm pretty confident on this point. my main problem right now, is for instance to access last calls and current messages...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check out the private CoreTelephony APIs, esp CTCallCenter.h. You can dump the private headers with this tool: https://rubygems.org/gems/private-dumper

And check out other private headers here: https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/

You might also find some more info here: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page

This app demonstrates how to access the call-log even without private APIs and jailbreaking: https://github.com/nst/spyphone

I'm not sure though, if it is possible to completely re-build the Phone.app with private APIs without jailbreaking.

- Johannes